# Cannot register device with TalkJs for push notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I am working on a React Native app that uses TalkJS. We want users to get a push notification for every message they receive. The messages are going through but we aren't getting notifications. We have uploaded our .p12 to the TalkJS dashboard and followed the docs for setting up a React Native project. Below is the relevant code we're injecting to the TalkUI loadScript. We followed https://talkjs.com/docs/Features/Notifications/Mobile_Push_Notifications.html

```
const res = await window.talkSession.registerDevice({ platform: "ios", pushRegistrationId: "${deviceToken}"});

alert("registering deviceToken ${deviceToken} response: " + res)
```

We are getting the alert with the correct deviceToken but this method does not return anything. We tried .then and an error first callback but nothing is coming back from this method.

Edit: this method is not designed to return anything, so the response is expected to be empty.

Comment: It would be great if someone with more reputation could make TalkJS a tag

Comment: [The registerDevice method](https://talkjs.com/docs/Reference/JavaScript_Chat_SDK/Session.html#Session.registerDevice) isn't supposed to return anything, as its return type is `Promise<void>`. How do you obtain the `deviceToken`, are you sure that it's working? Have you tried sending a test push notification using that `deviceToken` as a target to check if it's working?

Comment: From the docs I assumed it was returning a promise, so thanks for clearing that up. I guess this is an impossible thing to confirm then. My method of getting the device token is solid, I’m thinking now it’s an issue with my certificate. Is there a way to check user device tokens in the TalkJs console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Promise was designed to not return anything as Kapobajza mentioned.

From their support chat: "We have an issue regarding push notifications on iOS when using React Native."

Edit: this issue has been resolved. In addition to work that needed to be done by the TalkJS team, push notifications require a user to have a 'role', as is very loosely implied in the [Overview for Push Notifications](https://talkjs.com/docs/Features/Notifications/#a-role)